# After creating an elastic Job agent on Azure, export is failing

Tags: sql-server, azure, elasticsearch, export, jobs

I created an elastic job agent on the Azure Portal and didn't create any jobs. I see this Elastic job has created a jab database with several job related objects. Now I am not able to export data-tier application, it is failing with the following error.

> Error SQL71501: Error validating element [jobs_internal].[visible_targets_formatted]:
> View: [jobs_internal].[visible_targets_formatted] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [jobs_internal].[database_credentials].[C],
> [jobs_internal].[database_credentials].[name] or [jobs_internal].[targets].[C]. Error SQL71501: Error validating element [jobs]: Schema: [jobs] has an unresolved reference to object [##MS_JobAccount##]. Error SQL71501: Error validating element [jobs_internal]:
> Schema: [jobs_internal] has an unresolved reference to object [##MS_JobAccount##].

Any idea how to backup?

Answer (score 0):

I created a test and got the same error. This is potentially a bug, you can refer this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8489434-1bba-4e45-bf91-eafafbfcd041/cant-export-database-since-this-database-was-made-a-job-database-for-elastic-jobs-agent?forum=ssdsgetstarted).